# IF statement in an mysql query with check in array

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I'm trying to put 3 IF statements in an query instead of adding some php code.
The error that is shown is `FUNCTION admin_demo.in_array does not exist`

```
if($pr_aantal[$i] > 0)
{
    // voer query uit
    $sql = "INSERT INTO planning_producten
        (
            planning_id,
            product_id,
            aantal,
            datum_snijden,
            datum_zetten,
            datum_uitbesteed,
            user_id
        )
        VALUES
        (
            '".$planning_id."',
            '".$pr_id[$i]."',
            '".$pr_aantal[$i]."',
            IF(in_array('1', '".$pr_bewerking_id[$i]."'), STR_TO_DATE('".$datum_snijden."','%d-%m-%Y'), '0000-00-00'),
            IF(in_array('2', '".$pr_bewerking_id[$i]."'), STR_TO_DATE('".$datum_zetten."','%d-%m-%Y'), '0000-00-00'),
            IF(in_array('3', '".$pr_bewerking_id[$i]."'), STR_TO_DATE('".$datum_uitbesteden."','%d-%m-%Y'), '0000-00-00'),
            '".$_SESSION['user_id']."'
        )
    ";

    // resultaat van query
    if(!$res = mysql_query($sql,$con))
    {
        include('includes/errors/database_error.php');
    }
}
```

`$pr_bewerking_id[$i]` is created with:

```
while ($row_i = mysql_fetch_array($res_i))
{
    $i++;

    // maak select name
    $name_bewerking_id = 'name_bewerking_id'.$i;
    ?>

    <tr valign="top">
        <td>
        <select name="<?php echo $name_bewerking_id ?>[]" multiple="multiple" size="2">
        <?php
            $sql_bew = "SELECT id, bewerking FROM bewerkingen ORDER BY orderby ASC";
            $res_bew = mysql_query($sql_bew,$con);
            while ($row_bew = mysql_fetch_assoc($res_bew))
            { ?>
                <option value="<?php echo $row_bew['id']; ?>"><?php echo $row_bew['bewerking']; ?></option>
        <?php } ?>
        </select>
        </td>
    </tr>
<?php }
```

And send thru

```
$pr_bewerking_id[$i] = array();

for ($i = 0; $i <= $pr_aantal_regels; $i++)
{
    $pr_bewerking_id[$i] = $_POST['name_bewerking_id'.$i];
}
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: What are you trying to do with the if? cause of course it wont work there.

Answer (score -1):

I think you want to change this:

```
IF(in_array('1', '".$pr_bewerking_id[$i]."'),
```

To this:

```
IF(FIND_IN_SET('1', '" . $csv_string . "'),
```

You also have SQL injection vulnerabilities in your code. Use `mysql_real_escape_string` or parameterized queries.

Comment: That works but now it always puts '0000-00-00' in the database.
If I add mysql_real_escape_string it destroys my array.

Comment: @Muiter: Use implode with comma to convert your array to a string.

Comment: Trying to use implode -> Invalid arguments passed and when echod the emploded variable it shows $pr_bewerking_id_imploded[$i] instead of it's contents.